# How we can execute a Jupyter notebook python script automatically in Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I used terraform to create Sagemaker notebook instance and deploy Jupyter notebook python script to create and deploy a regression model.

I was able to run the scribe and create the model successfully via AWS console manually. However, I could not find a way to get it executed automatically. I even tried executing the script via shell commands through notebook instance’s lifecycle configuration. However, it did not work as expected.  Any other idea please?

Comment: Are you using a custom environment?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by a custom environment. However, I am using notebook instances and Jupyter notebook Sagemaker provisions by default.

Comment: When you want to execute this script? All the time you start on sagemaker or at a given time of the day?

Comment: I need to start the script to build the model whenever I start the notebook instance via terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. Passed the below script to notebook instance as lifecycle configuration.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
source activate python3
pip install runipy
nohup runipy <<path_to_the_jupyter_notebook>> &
source deactivate
EOF
```

Comment: The "nohup" and "&" is the critical bit! I once had this lifecycle config failing to start the Notebook instance, most probably because it was waiting for the script to finish running and was timing-out.

Comment: That is right. It would be failing as there would be time-out.